# How to remove body tag margin in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

The Angular 4 **app.component.html** does not provide a `body` tag which can be styled to remove the **body** tag padding.

[image: screenshot showing margin]

The following in **app.component.css** also didn't work:

```
body {
margin : 0;
}
```

Is there any way to remove the margin?

Comment: try adding `!important`. Eg. `padding-top: 0px !important;`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should put your css code into style.css, not app.component.css

Comment: Why does it work in `style.css` and not in `app.component.css`? What is the difference? I thought that the only difference is that `style.css` is for defining global css, so if I define a style in `app.component.css` it should apply anyway

Comment: Because, CSS written in `app.component.css` applies only to HTML in `app.component.html` by default. If you want CSS from `app.component.css` to be visible globally you should add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in `app.component.ts`

Answer (score 10):

**NOTE: make sure you edit the css which is linked to the page**

If you want to "disable" the default css values in HTML tags, you should try to check out "reset.css" and get a grasp about the idea, how you should be able to make a new site without worrying the various paddings and margins. Also if you do

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

it will likely solve this.

Comment: [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 4):

```
::ng-deep * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add style at global level (index.html OR Styles.css).

**index.html**

```
<style>
      body {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left:10px;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

working on angular 8, seems to be use below css style as angular 8 has changed some thing and below style should be used.

```
;body {
   padding: 20px;
  }
```